# Insert values in Windows register using C++

Tags: c++, windows, registry, windows-server-2008

I want to insert temporary data into Windows register every second. The question is what will the performance impact of inserting new data and replacing old one every second?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the amount of the data. Windows registry is pretty robust and well optimized for intensive reading and writing. For an impression, try watching registry access with Process Explorer (downloadable from MS - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) for a while. As long as you keep your hive tidy you should be fine.